# Comment & User PHP/SQL will not insert data

Tags: php, debugging, authentication, comments

***EDIT***
Thank you! I made the change it is inserting the data correctly now. I knew it was something simple... perks of coding for hours I guess.
Back to work, off to create a reply function....
Thanks again!

I recently changed my code to allow for users to comment and reply on a website I am developing to help improve my coding. I followed a tutorial on Youtube for my comments, and I am having a hard time connecting the User Login system I created with the comment database. 
If anyone could give me a nudge in the right direction I will greatly appreciate it. (I have been debugging for hours... I feel like it is something super simple or obvious, I need another pair of eyes to just point at what the problem is)

The problem: I can comment on my webpage, it will insert the comment and date into the database. The uid is not saved in the database. The website will not output results/comment.

```html
///in the index to display comments

    <?php
echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$_SESSION['u_id']."'>
 <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'>
  <textarea name='message'></textarea><br>
 <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit'>Comment</button>
 </form>";
    
    getComments($conn);
?>
```

```js
comments.php

<?php
function setComments($conn) {
 if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
     $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        
        $sql = "INSERT INTO thecomments (uid, date, message) VALUES ('$uid', '$date', '$message')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
}

function getComments($conn) { 
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM thecomments";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $id = $row['uid'];
     $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='$id'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        if ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
             echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
            echo $row2['uid']."<br>";
            echo $row['date']."<br>";
            echo nl2br($row['message']);
          echo "</p>";
           if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
             if ($_SESSION['u_id'] == $row2['u_id']) {
                    echo "<form class='delete-form' method='POST' action='".deleteComments($conn)."'>
                          <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>
                          <button type='submit' name='commentDelete'>Delete</button>
                      </form>
                      <form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='editcomment.php'>
                          <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>
                          <input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$row['uid']."'>
                          <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$row['date']."'>
                          <input type='hidden' name='message' value='".$row['message']."'>
                          <button>Edit</button>
                      </form>";
              } else {
                echo "<form class='edit-form' method='POST' action='".deleteComments($conn)."'>
                          <input type='hidden' name='cid' value='".$row['cid']."'>
                          <button type='submit' name='commentDelete'>Reply</button>
                      </form>";
              }
            } else {
             echo "<p class='commentmessage'>You need to be logged in to reply!</p>";
            }
         echo "</div>";
        }
    }  
}

function editComments($conn) {
 if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
     $cid = $_POST['cid'];
     $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        
        $sql = "UPDATE thecomments SET message='$message' WHERE cid='$cid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}

function deleteComments($conn) {
 if (isset($_POST['commentDelete'])) {
     $cid = $_POST['cid'];
        
        $sql = "DELETE FROM thecomments WHERE cid='$cid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
}
?>
```

```js
login.php

<?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
  $uid = $_POST['uid'];
  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

  //Error handlers
  //Check if inputs are empty
  if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
   header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty");
   exit();
  }
  else {
   //Check if username exists in the database USING PREPARED STATEMENTS
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid=?";
   $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
   if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
       header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
       exit();
   }
   else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $uid);
    //Run query in database
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    //Get results from query
       $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['pwd']);
     //If they didn't match!
     if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
      header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
      exit();
     }
     //If they did match!
     elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
      //Set SESSION variables and log user in
      $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
      $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
      $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
      $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['uid'];
      header("Location: main.php?login=success");
      exit();
     }
       } else {
         header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
       }
   }
  }

  //Close the prepared statement
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

 } else {
  header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
  exit();
 }
```

I appreciate your time and help. Off to debugging some more, will update if anything new.

Comment: In you `<form>` tag fix your `action=` attribute. It should point to a page not to a php function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your line in the index to use `$_SESSION['u_uid']`. That's what session variable you are setting it to.

```
<input type='hidden' name='uid' value='".$_SESSION['id']."'>
```

Using `var_dump($_SESSION)` would be a good idea when you can't figure out why a variable is not getting data.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that, I will implement this to help debug in the future

Comment: Why was my answer downvoted? It seems this is the underlying problem.

Comment: Did you fix the issue by changing the form action or the above variable change?

Comment: I changed the variable, and everything is inserting & outputting fine now. Changing the action to the comments.php did not do anything. This solution seemed to help the best for me

Comment: Just an FYI: doing an `echo ('<!-- <variable name> = ' . var_dump($_SESSION) . ' -->');` will output the variable information in the source code of a page without breaking the page in any way.

Comment: Please accept this as the answer to your issue if it helped. Thank you!